How to export all user list in AppStore?
For internal audit, we want to extract all users from our AppStore instead of viewing it from there.
In Google PlayStore, we can easily "Export user list" as shown below.

However I can't find similar item on AppStore. Is it available, or this is not possible in AppStore?


From Appstoreconnect Go to the app you are interested in extracting its users.
Go to TestFlight
form the left side menu, from Testers choose All
Press in the icon with a box and arrow down (see the pic below)
now you have csv file of all testers of this app

Note: I think you must have admin privileges to do this.
UPDATE: The only way to get all the users in App Store Connect is to use app store APIs.
GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users

This will get a list of the users on your team.


These are tester list. I want user list of the AppStore account we have (across all apps)
